# Spring MVC REST - standard request body wrapper

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

What is the best way to achieve a common REST request body unwrap effect with Spring MVC `@RestController` ?

In other words, assuming I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = POST)
    public Object hello(@RequestBody MyDTO dto) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like the actual post body to be:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "payload": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Which can be represented by the following class:

```
public class ApiRequestDTO<TPayload> {
    private String   version;
    private TPayload payload;
    ...

    // Getters and Setters...
    ...
}
```

So in this particular case the client would send an instance of `ApiRequestDTO<MyDTO>`.

I achieved the opposite (response body wrapper) using a `@ControllerAdvice`, but I notice that it won't work exactly for the request body. One possible approach I can see is to decorate all the relevant message converters. But I was wondering if there is a better approach?

Comment: I do not understand what is "standard" about that. Do you want to know how to send a JSON representation?

Comment: I replaced the word "standard" with "common". What I'm trying to achieve is not to have to use `ApiRequest<SomeDTO>` in the method signature of all my controllers, but make it transparent to the controller.